# How to retrieve all many_to_many relations for each objects in a single query

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, orm

I have four tables :

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    item_recipe = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='item_recipe')
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='RecipeItem')


class RecipeItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Item(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    effects = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True, default=list)
    pods = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default="Ressource")
    image = models.URLField()

class Prix(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    prix_x1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    prix_x10 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    prix_x100 = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A recipe is composed of 1 to 8 Items with a certain quantity indicated is the RecipeItem table.

I would like a query that gives me the price of every Recipe.
In other word, a query that get all items and its prices for every recipe and sum it.

I don't find a way to do that without a for loop.

**EDIT**

Here is what i have currently, it's not pretty and not effective ..

```
items = Recipe.objects.all().select_related('item').annotate(
        prix1_ressource=Subquery(
            Prix.objects.filter(
                item=OuterRef('items')
            ).values('prix_x1').exclude(prix_x1__isnull=True).order_by('-saved_at')[:1]
        ),
        prix1_item=Subquery(
            Prix.objects.filter(
                item=OuterRef('item_recipe')
            ).values('prix_x1').exclude(prix_x1__isnull=True).order_by('-saved_at')[:1]
        )
    ).exclude(prix1_item__isnull=True).values('id', 'item_recipe__name', 'prix1_ressource', 'items__name',
                                              'recipeitem__quantity', 'prix1_item',
                                              'item_recipe__type', 'item_recipe')

for id in np.unique(items.values_list('id', flat=True)):
    item = items.filter(id=id)
    try:
        prix_craft = sum([i['recipeitem__quantity'] * i['prix1_ressource'] for i in item])
        gain = item[0]['prix1_item'] - prix_craft

    except TypeError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

There is really not a nice SQL way. At some point either you or Django will have to iterate over all the items in a query and sum them. Perhaps you could make it a little more efficient by using an Inner join, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), using it to preload the items. But resolving the item's current `Prix` might require a separate query each time.

Comment: I see .. And do you have an idea on how to make it as effective as possible ? Because currently my loop is very long, like 12s ..